# Adding a param to a method in a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, methods

I am looking for a way to add a extra param to a method in my plugin.

This example I use an update method, but it needs an extra param to tell what to update.

// plugin wrapper

```
  ;(function($, window, document, undefined){

      var pluginName = 'myPlugin01';

      function Plugin(element, options){

          // vars here
      };

      Plugin.prototype = {

          init: function(){

          // init code here

          },
          update: function(param){

              // need the param value in this method
              if(param == 'bottom'){
                  alert('bottom it is...')
              }else{
                  alert('top it is...')
              }

          },
      };

      $.fn[pluginName] = function(option) {
          return this.each(function() {
              var $this   = $(this);
              var data    = $this.data(pluginName);
              var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
              if (!data){ 
                $this.data(pluginName, (data = new Plugin(this, options)))
              }
              if (typeof option == 'string'){
                   data[option]();
              }
          });
      };

      $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
          option1: true
      };

  })(jQuery, window, document);
```

// how I want to use it

```
$('.element').myPlugin('update','bottom');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can add additional arg to the `$.fn[pluginName]` and use it for `update` or any method

```
//Added additional arg
$.fn[pluginName] = function(option, mydata) {
```

And then in the calling part,

```
data[option](mydata);
```